# Dynamically Select An HTML option based previous select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How do you dynamically select an HTML option based on a previous select tag?
[Image of current project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ5tY.png)

Below is the code I have done to get there. I expect the size select tag to be disabled until a user selects a colour like Neon Blue and then the size option tag populates all the sizes that are available for that specific color like this [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLKHa.png)

```
    <!-- product attributes -->
              <div class="product-attributes">

              <select class="product-select-attributes" name="p-attrib" id="p-attrib">
                        <?php
                          echo "<option selected disabled>Color</option>";
                          //echo "<option value={$productID}>$color</option>";
                          foreach($arrays as $nxt) {                                    
                            //echo "<option value={$nxt['pID']}>{$nxt['attrib']} <p> | </p> {$nxt['quantity']} <p>left</p></option>";
                            echo "<option value={$productID}>{$nxt['color']}</option>";
                          }

                        ?>
                  </select>

                <br>
                <hr>


              <select class="product-select-attributes" name="p-attrib" id="p-attrib">
                      <?php
                        echo "<option selected disabled>Size</option>";
                        foreach($arrays as $nxt) {  
                          //echo "<option value={$nxt['pID']}>{$nxt['attrib']}  <p> | </p> {$nxt['stock']} <p>left</p> </option>";
                          echo "<option value={$productID}>{$nxt['size']}</option>";
                        }
                      ?>
                </select>
              
              </div>

              <!-- add to cart button -->
              <div class="product-add-to-cart">
                      <div class="product-atc">
                          <a href="#">Add To Cart</a>
                      </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Is there an issue with your code? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Your post lacks a lot of context. Are you storing the data in a database? What does the structure look like? Based on the product ID, you will generate a two-dimensional array of the colors and the sizes available to that color. Then you can add an event listener with JavaScript that listens for changes on the color dropdown to then populate the size dropdown.

Comment: Looks like what you need is, when the user select the color, you have to do an ajax call to retrieve the sizes available to the product/color and then dynamically create the options for the second <select> tag